# How can i highlight double spaces in Emacs config file?

Tags: emacs

I am searching for adding options in my Emacs's config file, in order to highlight every double space in my files.

I usually use Vim, and the command i would like to use in Emacs is this:

highlight double_space ctermbg=blue
match double_space /\ {2}\|\s+$/

After many research, also on google, i don't find what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can had this line in your config file.

```
(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-regexp "  " 'hi-blue)))
```